# FFMPEG - Interpolate frames or add motion blur

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing, video-encoding, avconv

I just watched the [trailer for the hobbit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1s6A709gFUQ), and [a trailer for the avengers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lfwjzNB--5k) which both feature an increased framerate. A lot of the comments state that this isn't "true" 60fps since it was not shot at 60fps, but actually a lower frame-rate that has been interpolated.

[image]

If this is the case, **is there any way that I can convert some of my existing media in Linux with ffmpeg or avconv in the same way in order to create this "illusion"?**

I can understand if higher framerates are not to other's tastes, but not the point of this post.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try

```
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -filter:v tblend -r 120 result.mp4
```

or this from https://superuser.com/users/114058/mulvya

```
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -filter:v minterpolate -r 120 result.mp4
```

There are filter for motion blur

Comment: `minterpolate` works really well!

Comment: the link leads to a user page.

Comment: I'm changing this to the correct answer (from butterflow) as this answer is just about using ffmpeg which is closer to the asked question. Also, installing Butterflow on Ubuntu 18.04 or later has proved impossible for me, and I've tested minterpolate and it does indeed work extremely well. I use this command: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "minterpolate=fps=60:mi_mode=mci:mc_mode=aobmc:me_mode=bidir:vsbmc=1" output.mp4`

Comment: Can this be used to add motion blur and keep the original frame rate? I don't want to interpolate frames, I just want to add blur to existing frames.

Answer (score 6):

You can use Butterflow as it uses ffmpeg https://github.com/dthpham/butterflow

> It's a command-line tool that can:
>
> Increase a video's frame rate by rendering new frames based on motion
>   (pixel-warping + blending). Make smooth motion videos (simple blending
>   between frames). Leverage new frames/increase in frame rates to make
>   fluid slow motion videos.

Comment: I wrote a script that ubuntu 16.04 users can use to install the tool: http://blog.programster.org/ubuntu-16-04-install-butterflow/
It takes a lot of grunt and I found I had to use it on videos no larger than 640 x 480 if I wanted to get a result in a reasonable amount of time. Obviously hardware dependent.

Answer (score 2):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v "minterpolate=mi_mode=2" output.mp4
```

is for simple dynamic fast frame interpolation using a little bit of motion blur and calculations.

Comment: Hi... Could you explain how `minterpolate=mi_mode=2` differs from just plain `minterpolate`? I'm curious to learn the difference.

Answer (score 1):

you can try with Slowmovideo.
look the demo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YAVRnEg0Vps

Answer (score 1):

I know that my question asked about **converting** video to a higher framerate with interpolated frames, so this answer can never be the "true" answer, but I have since found the [Smooth Video Project (SVP)](https://www.svp-team.com/wiki/Main_Page) which works on Linux, Mac, and Windows ([Download Link](https://www.svp-team.com/wiki/Download)).

This tool is free and takes any video and interpolates frames on-the-fly like your TV might do, so you don't have to spend ages re-encoding your videos. It takes a bit of grunt though so I don't know how well it will work on laptops, but works brilliantly on my desktop quad core machines.

Ubuntu Linux users can read [my post](http://blog.programster.org/tag/svp/) on how to set it up.

Comment: Note! The Linux version (64-bit only) appears to be freeware, but this plugin is not open source. The Windows and macOS versions are $10. The plugin does seem extremely compelling though, I generally prefer open source stuff but this is on my to-try list.

Answer (score 0):

We have a Video Frame Doubler System in the cloud.

This is a solution to convert video from 30fps to 60fps up to 5k (5400x2700) resolution using ffmpeg.

If you wanted to convert a 30-minute file with this resolution, you would need two weeks or so.
But we can do it in about a day. (In some cases, it may take even longer).
In addition, there is almost no loss of image quality, which is common with video interpolation in deep learning.

Please use it for distributing 5K VR video(s).

https://ec.remaster.ai/index.php?route=product/category&path=85

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the smoothest-looking solution, but it is certainly WAAAAAY faster:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf tmix=frames=8:weights="1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1" output.mp4
```

The more frames you set the more motion effect is applied. The weights must equal the same number of frames.

Comment: That doesn't look useful to me for interpolation though, should only add lots of motion blur. 
To me this looks only useful for framerate reduction, to get smoother, less stuttery video.